# Getting error while running "yo jhipster-ionic"

Tags: ionic-framework, jhipster

I am new in jhpster-ionic, following this link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-ionic

Everything was fine until I ran this command:
"yo jhipster-ionic --force" in an empty folder.

After running this command, I am getting this error:
[image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: How did you install jhipster-ionic?  Does re-running `npm install -g generator-jhipster-ionic` fix your issue?  `generator-jhipster` is a dependency of `generator-jhipster-ionic` and should be installed automatically in the path from your error.

Comment: @Jon, no it did not fix the issue. After running npm install -g generator-jhipster-ionic, following error occurs:

https://postimg.org/image/mzf7v2xcj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the dependencies of `generator-jhipster-ionic`.  Change directories to `D:\works\jhipster\chharkoi2\chharkoi2\node_modules\generator-jhipster-ionic` and run `npm install`.  These dependencies are normally installed when you install a package through npm.